# Problem with lxfonts

Tags: fonts

When I compile this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{A}$
\end{document}
```

I get

an "incomplete" calligraphic "A".

[image: calligraphic A]

If I use other fonts, everything seems fine.

Any idea about this?

Comment: TL2014 don't give me your error/warning.

Comment: In MikTeX 2.9 either.

Comment: I don't get an error/warning too, but if you look closely to the letter, what do you see at the top of it? (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX, lxfonts 2013/09/03)

Comment: Show an image of your result (problem!)

Comment: I get the same result, TL2014. Could be a bug in the font I suppose, or just how it's designed.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's definitely a bug in the font design.

Comment: I don't seem a problem, it's an excellent design of the `A` in form calligraphic (different of others). I like this.

Answer (score 7):

It is just as it is designed; you may consier it a bug or a feature, but that one is the shape of the calligraphic A of the LX fonts I designed.